# Parse malformed attribute using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract an attribute that contains an invalid unescaped quote:

```
<meta content="mal"formed">
```

When using BeautifulSoup like this:

```
soup.find('meta')['content']
```

And as expected, the result is `mal`.

Is there a way to make BeautifulSoup treat the unescaped quote as a part of the attribute, so the result will be `mal"formed`?

Comment: my solution did not work. I don't know f there is a solution to this..

Comment: what happens to the `formed"` part of the tag? Two approaches: 1. Find the second part of the malformed attribute and fund a way of identifying it as such 2. create your own iterative search function to append to BeautifulSoup that will handle malformed attributes.

Comment: Could you please post the complete HTML you have? Also, what do you know about the source HTML beforehand? For instance, are there always double quotes issues inside the meta and only there..?

Comment: @alecxe this is the complete HTML, and the attribute is not always malformed. I can solve it using regex, but I wonder if there's a more robust method using BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @Tzach:  If it's malformed in any possible way, then no.  If it's malformed in one (or a few specific ways), then sure - as you mentioned, just pre-process it with a regex.  Beautiful soup takes a parser (it comes with some by default).  None of the ones it comes with fix this issue.  You could write your own, but a regex would be far easier.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error using regex, this is my best solution so far:

```
html = re.sub('(content="[^"=]+)"([^"=]+")', r'\1&quot;\2', html)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)    
soup.find('meta')['content']
```

**Explanation:** at first I tried to run the regex only on the desired element. However when doing `str(element)`, BeautifulSoup doesn't return the original html, but a reformatted html which already doesn't contain the `formed` (the invalid) part of the attribute.

So my solution is based on searching for this exact kind of malformed attributes on the entire HTML, and fixing it using regex. Of course it's very specific to my case.

A better (and hopefully less hackish) solution will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I've tried to fix that broken HTML:

- [different `BeautifulSoup` parsers](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers) - `html.parser`, `html5lib`, `lxml`
- [`lxml.html` with and without `recover=True`](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parser-options)

  ```
  from lxml.html import HTMLParser, fromstring, tostring

  data = """<meta content="mal"formed">"""

  parser = HTMLParser(recover=True)
  print tostring(fromstring(data, parser=parser))
  ```

  Prints:

  ```
  <html><head><meta content="mal" formed></head></html>
  ```
- firing up `Firefox` and `Chrome` via [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) and feeding them the broken meta tag:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  data = """<meta content="mal"formed">"""

  driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # or webdriver.Firefox
  driver.get("about:blank")

  driver.execute_script("document.head.innerHTML = '{html}';".format(html=data))
  data = driver.page_source
  driver.close()

  print data
  ```

  Prints:

  ```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta content="mal" formed"="" /></head><body></body></html>
  ```

Different tools interpreted the HTML differently but no tool provided the desired output.

I guess, depending on how much you know about the data, pre-processing it with regular expressions might be a practical solution in this case.